# Where can I ask about coding style?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a question about **coding style / indentation and alignment**, and I don't know where (or if) there is a Stack Exchange site suitable for that.

I only figured that it would not be an o.k. question for Stack Overflow, because it is both ***off-topic*** and ***primarily opinion based***, and I don't think it's suitable for Code Review either.

---

A sample question:

How should I align the following long construct to make it a little more readable?

```
return LongClassName.DoSomething<TReturn, TExceptionOnFailure, TPassedData>(myReturn, new MyException(), this.helper.Data);
```

---

Where can I ask such questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you nailed the problem: usually such questions are primarily opinion based, which is off-topic almost everywhere.

Stack Overflow is a no-go, so is Software Engineering in my opinion.

It [might](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) fit on Code Review:

> If you have a working piece of code from your project and are looking for open-ended feedback in the following areas:
>
> - Best practices and design pattern usage

I am not sure if code style falls in the "best practices" category, but you can always ask on [their meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: thank you for the answer. I didn't even know they had a meta too (stupid, I know). I think I will try to ask there first, thank you.

Comment: **Note**: [Best practices in general](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) are off-topic.